# Group array results in Alphabetic order PHP (continued)

Tags: php, foreach, group-by

I'm sorry for the uncreative title.

I'm trying to group my array alphabetically. [The accepted answer in this question (by Hugo Delsing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210480/group-array-results-in-alphabetic-order-php) helped greatly to my task, but I still want to take things a bit further...

here's my current code:

```
$records = ['7th Trick', 'Jukebox', 'Dynamyte', '3rd Planet'];
$lastChar = '';
sort($records, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

foreach($records as $val) {
    $char = strtolower($val[0]);

    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
        if ($lastChar !== '') echo "</ul>";

        echo "<h2>".strtoupper($char)."</h2><ul>";
        $lastChar = $char;
    }

    echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';

}
echo "</ul>";
```

I want to make things so that non-alphabetic items would get grouped together instead of separated individually.

---

**example:**

"7th Trick" and "3rd Planet" get grouped together as non-alphabetic instead of displayed separately under "7" and "3" category respectively.

---

any idea how to do it?

Comment: Make your question clear with some raw input data+ code what you tried+where you stuck+desired output what you want. Statements and links will not going to help  any-one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array results in Alphabetic order PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210480/group-array-results-in-alphabetic-order-php)

Comment: Related and a very good candidate for code extension to suit your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371496/group-array-elements-by-letter-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add one line to your existing code to accomplish this.

```
$char = strtolower($val[0]);

// Convert $char to one value if it isn't a letter
if (!ctype_alpha($char)) $char = 'Non-alphabetic';

if ($char !== $lastChar) {
```

The rest of it should work the same.

Comment: Splendid! Sexy one-liner saves the day!! XD

Comment: This will not group non-alphabetic entries though, which seems like what you would want, given that the alphabetic entries *are* grouped.

Comment: @ScottCWilson I thought the OP was asking for all the non-alphabetic entries to be combined into one group. This should do that.

Comment: You are right; I missed the fact that a sort was called in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the alphas from the array and show them after printing the alphas.

```
<?php
$records = ['7th Trick', 'Jukebox', 'Dynamyte', '3rd Planet'];
$lastChar = '';
sort($records, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

$alpha = array();
$non_alpha = array(); 
foreach($records as $val) {
   if (ctype_alpha($val[0])) {
      $alpha[] = $val; 
   } else { 
      $non_alpha[] = $val; 
   }
}
foreach($alpha as $val) {
    $char = strtolower($val[0]);

    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
        if ($lastChar !== '') echo "</ul>";

        echo "<h2>".strtoupper($char)."</h2><ul>";
        $lastChar = $char;
    }

    echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';

}
echo "</ul>";
if (sizeof($non_alpha) > 0) { 
   echo "<h2>Digits</h2><ul>";
   foreach ($non_alpha as $val) { 
      echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
   } 
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, your code worked nicely... but the other answer is just too sexy to for me... XD